# Combine keypress and keyup - jQuery

Tags: jquery, keypress, keydown, keyup

I'm trying to develop a jQuery plugin to do an action when the user enter a specific keyphrase.

For example, I want to match "HELLO" on keyup.

```
var controllerKey = [];
$(window).keyup(function(evt) {
    var code = evt.keyCode ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    controllerKey.push(code);
}
[...]
```

Then, I compare my controllerKey with my string "HELLO" (thanks to str.charCodeAt()) and some others things but this isn't important here.
Everything works fine at this point.

**My problem** happens when I want to match "HeLLo" (in fact when the string had some **uppercase**). I saw on forums that keyup or keydown don't make any difference.

So I use keypress which manage it very well but keypress doesn't allow me to match arrow keys and so one (in Chrome).

**I want to know if it's possible to combine keypress and keyup (only when keypress doesn't match the event).**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are they entering this phrase inside an input?  Also you mention your problem is comparing strings of different cases and then you are asking about keypress and keyup?

Comment: No. It's a plugin to do like a "konami code" but with the password of your choice. I'm comparing the first string (key-phrase) with the user input

Comment: I think I'm too old to know what konomi code is however I have provided you an answer about combining both the events..

Comment: You can have a try here : http://konamicodesites.com/
Press the following keys : "Up / Up / Down / Down / Left / Right / Left / Right / B / A"

Comment: Ok, I get it now, just didn't know the name.. Reminds me of commando from back in the day. +1 for teaching me that one!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can combine them like this:

```
$(window).on('keyup keypress', function(e) {
   if (e.type=="keyup") {

   } else {
      // it is keypress
   }
});
```

Comment: Consequently you can easily compare strings by s.toUpperCase() == t.toUpperCase()

Comment: Your answer will help me. Thanks. (I don't want to use upperCase for the comparaison because I want to keep this information)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **hidden input** and **key events** in order to have cross browser case sensitive compare.